# MySqlDataReader executes command, but reader.Read() outputs error message

Tags: c#, sql

I do not really know how to ask this well, but will try to describe.

I have created a mysql command, that should insert data into a table and it does exactly what I want, but if statement reader.Read() jumps into an error saying it failed to create the user, even though the user was created.

Why is this happening?

```
private void iconButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create user in mysql
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=sklad;UID=root;PASSWORD=;");
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO users (username, password, role) VALUES ('" + username.Text + "', '" + password.Text + "', '" + role.Text + "') ", conn);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    
    if(reader.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Uživatel vytvořen!", "E-Skladovka.cz - Uživatel vytvořen", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to create user");
    }
    
    reader.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
}
```

I tried to search, but as long as I do not know how to ask properly, I can not search properly.

Comment: INSERT commands don't return rows, so there's nothing  to read, hence read() returns false and it goes to your  else block

Comment: You should be using ExecuteNonQuery to run this, not ExecuteReader. Consult tutorials, examples etc showing insert, update or delete queries.

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***. also: ***never*** store passwords as plain text.

Comment: Other issues with your code: you have **dangerous** SQL injection going on here, you need to parameterize. You need to dispose your connection and command (and reader, not relevant here because you should use `ExecuteNonQuery`) with `using`. You should not hard-code the connection string into the code, instead put it into a settings file. I won't get into storing plain-text passwords, but suffice to say it's a bad idea

Comment: As others have stated, "Reader" indicates that it's used for reading data (ie: Select statements).

Comment: You may find it easier to use the MS documentation. While the names of the methods are different, the usage is similar - "SqlCommand" usage is similar to "MySqlCommand". There may be some differences so it'll be necessary to cross-reference with the MySQL documentation.